# Microsoft dynamics CRM 2013 missing New, Delete, Copy a Link, Run Report tool bar

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I recently restored my production database to my test area, but when users login they are unable to see the tabs shown in the screen shot below. I am able to view them on the server but on any other machine i am also unable to view. I have full rights in the organisation.

[Missing tab in ms dynamics crm 2013](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGZ99.png)

This is what i can view on the server

[Contains the tabs in the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p08Hp.png)

Also noted is i can not open an email or case by clicking on the title, i have done my research online but i have not seen anything of this sort.

Comment: try deleting the cache of browser, or a server restart ?

Comment: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/168441

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, delete the Microsoft Internet Explorer cache. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Exit the Microsoft CRM Web client and the Microsoft Dynamics CRM
   client for Outlook.
2. Start Microsoft Internet Explorer.
3. Click Tools, and then click Internet Options.
4. Click Delete Cookies, and then click OK.
5. Click Delete Files, and then click OK.